# LINQ query syntax

Tags: c#, linq

I have two different lists where one is a bunch of ID's as in a `List<int> idsList`, the other however is a list of objects like `List<MyObject> myObjectList` where the object looks like this:

```
class MyObject{
    private List<int> ids;

     public MyObject(List<int> ids){
      this.ids = ids;
     }

     public List<int> Ids{
       get{
          return ids;
       }
     }
}
```

As you can see each object can contain one or multiple IDs (never zero or null ids). So what I need at the end is to know what objects in myObjectList have any id(s) from my idsList. 
So far if I do:

```
var ids = from g in onScreen where g.Ids.Contains(myIntVariable) select g;
```

it would give me a list of the object(s) that contain myIntVariable. What I do not know how to do is to match the content of the idsList with the list in MyObject. 
Thanks!

Comment: By the way, I also tried this: from g in myObjectList where (from n in idsList select n).Contains(g.Ids) select g; and always get an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to go:

```
var listOfMyObjectsContainingAnIdFromIdsList = myObjectList.Where(myObject => myObject.Ids.Any(id => idsList.Contains(id)));
```

Comment: You can also do firstList.Intersect(secondList) to get the in common items.

Comment: In this same line, if I want a list of the IDS only that are in the objects in  List<MyObject> myObjectList what would that be then?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `g` is your object list and `idsList` is your int list:

```
foreach (var myObject in g.Where( obj => obj.Ids.Any( itemId => idsList.Contains(itemId) ) )) {
     //Use your myObject here
}
```

Hope it works,