# More LINQ syntax

Tags: c#, linq

I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11784977/linq-query-syntax) question earlier and that helped a lot. Then I realized I also need a list of IDs of the List that is a property in that object. Basically I want to end up with a list of integers generated from each list in those objects. Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Please make your question self-contained.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var ids = (from x in outerList
          from y in x.List
          select y).ToList();
```

Or to avoid dups:

```
var ids = (from x in outerList
          from y in x.List
          select y).Distinct().ToList();
```

For info, this could also be written:

```
var ids = outerList.SelectMany(x => x.List).ToList();
```

or:

```
var ids = outerList.SelectMany(x => x.List).Distinct().ToList();
```